# file is using by another process

Tags: c#, file-io, io

I'm a newbie on c# programming. I have a problem when I'm using `FileStream`. I want to retrieve picture from the database by searching ID of person in the database. AND IT WORKS!!. but when I try to retrieve picture of the person twice (inserting same ID twice). it will give IOException

```
"The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\dor\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\studbase\studbase\bin\Debug\foto.jpg' because it is being used by another process."
```

I have 1 button --> `buttonLoad` |
       1 pictureBox --> `pictureBoxPictADUStudent`

this is the code on buttonLoad

```
        string sql = "SELECT Size,File,Name FROM studgeninfo WHERE NIM = '"+textBoxNIM.Text+"'";
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionSQL);
        MySqlCommand comm = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);

        if (textBoxNIM.Text != "")
        {
            conn.Open();
            MySqlDataReader data = comm.ExecuteReader();

            while (data.Read())
            {

                int fileSize = data.GetInt32(data.GetOrdinal("size"));
                string name = data.GetString(data.GetOrdinal("name"));


                using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(name, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
                {
                        byte[] rawData = new byte[fileSize];
                        data.GetBytes(data.GetOrdinal("file"), 0, rawData, 0, fileSize);
                        fs.Write(rawData, 0, fileSize);
                        fs.Dispose();
                        pictureBoxPictADUStudent.BackgroundImage = new Bitmap(name);
                }
            }

            conn.Close();
        }

        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please Input Student NIM ", "Warning!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that the file is locked by `new Bitmap()`. So you have to make sure once the bitmap is loaded, it's lock on the file is disposed:

```
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(name, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
        {
                byte[] rawData = new byte[fileSize];
                data.GetBytes(data.GetOrdinal("file"), 0, rawData, 0, fileSize);
                fs.Write(rawData, 0, fileSize);
        }

        using (var bmpTemp = new Bitmap(name))
        {
            pictureBoxPictADUStudent.BackgroundImage= new Bitmap(bmpTemp);
        }
```

Update:
I updated my answer to reflect your latest answers.
For mor detailed information goto [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4803935/free-file-locked-by-new-bitmapfilepath)

Comment: The fs.Dispose() is now redundant and can be removed.

Comment: i have tried it. but it always give me IOException Error just like before.

Comment: for first searching, it is work. but when i search once again (without close the application) it give me the same error

Comment: @eliezeramon are you sure the ressource is not accessed at any other place?

Comment: i removed it. but still give IOException on FileStream fs = new FileStream(name,FileMode.Create,FileAccess.Read);

Comment: @derape . i will explain the proses. i have save image into database. and when i try to retrieve it using FileStream, in my folder bin/debug appear the picture from DB.

in my database have 2 ID with two pict.
08520060 and 0852061. 
when i search 08520060, it works. pict appear. when i search the second ID(08520061) it works. but when i search ID 08520060 again. the IOException appear.

Comment: @eliezeramon ah okay, is it possible that the "old" image is still assigned to the picturebox, thus it's still accessing the image? try `pictureBoxPictADUStudent.BackgroundImage = null;` before using the filestream

Comment: @derape is this right?

 while (data.Read())
                {
                        pictureBoxPictADUStudent.BackgroundImage = null;
                        
                        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(name, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
                        {
                          
                }
                pictureBoxPictADUStudent.BackgroundImage = new Bitmap(name);
            }

Answer (score 4):

You are opening the file here:

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(name, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
                                   // ^^^^ This is your filename..
```

..and `Bitmap` is also trying to open the file to read it.. here:

```
pictureBoxPictADUStudent.BackgroundImage = new Bitmap(name);
                                                   // ^^^^ You are using it again here
```

The `Bitmap` won't be able to read from the file while you're writing to it..

EDIT:

As pointed out in the comments, this can happen even though `fs.Dispose()` is being called. See here: [Does FileStream.Dispose close the file immediately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6350224/does-filestream-dispose-close-the-file-immediately)

Comment: But doesn't he call `fs.Dispose()` one line above? Why doesn't that release the file handle?

Comment: It's probably caused be the interal handling of the "using" which reserves fs until leaving the codeblock even if you dispose fs manually

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6350224/does-filestream-dispose-close-the-file-immediately

Comment: @Jason Actually I have just tested this and it appears that it doesn't work every time..

Comment: @BennorMcCarthy That appears to be what I am experiencing.

Comment: @voo Doubtful.. a file handle is a native resource. I wouldn't recommend it anyway.. you're forcing something to happen when you can let it happen naturally.

Answer (score -1):

write like this
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(name, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))

### {

---

}
pictureBoxPictADUStudent.BackgroundImage = new Bitmap(name);