# C# StreamWriter with using-block inside a while loop intermittently fails on slow network drive

Tags: c#, streamwriter, network-drive

I have a logging class in which I spawn a Task to append all messages from a `BlockingCollection<string>` to the log file, sleep two seconds, and repeat infinitely, until the fifo is completed.

This works fine for local files, but when writing to a slow network drive I'm getting intermittent failures at `using (StreamWriter sw)`: IOException - The process cannot access the file 'x.txt' because it is being used by another process.

I am *not* writing to the same file from two threads. There are 3-4 instances of my logger going, but each instance has a unique filename based on timestamp and guid. No external apps are accessing these files at the time.

**Even though the StreamWriter is disposed** by the using-block in the first trip through the while loop and I **sleep for a while**, the second trip through the while loop **somehow still finds the file to be open** at some lower level (The stack trace gets down to `System.IO.FileStream.Init`, and ultimately, `System.IO.__Error.WinIOError`.

I can intermittently, sometimes, reproduce the exception in a simple integration test that spins up 100 logger objects in a Parallel.For loop.

```
        private void FlushFifoToLogFile()
        {
            while (!_fifoLog.IsCompleted)
            {
                if (_fifoLog.Count > 0)
                {
                    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(_logFilePath, append:true))
                    {
                        while (_fifoLog.TryTake(out string line))
                        {
                            sw.WriteLine(line);
                        }
                    }
                }
                
                _flushCts.Token.WaitHandle.WaitOne(SLEEP_MILLISECONDS);
            }
        }
```

Comment: I would avoid this constant writelines. Instead I would append every line in a StringBuilder buffer and then call File.WriteAllLines.

Comment: Best way is to add a lock so only one thread goes through the code at one time.  There may be some STATIC methods in the library that is giving an issue.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/lock

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6350267/14868997 Intermittent connections can exacerbate the issue of delayed close (which is caused by the OS finishing up the file system writes). Best to just catch it and sleep again.

Comment: @Charlieface Yeah, catch & retry was the direction I was headed, but it would be nice to to have a way to really know what is failing under the hood.

Answer (score 1):

Per recommendation from @Charlieface, the lowest friction solution is a basic try/catch.

I also incorporated @Steve's StringBuilder suggestion.

```
        private void FlushFifoToLogFile()
        {
            while (!_fifoLog.IsCompleted)
            {
                if (_fifoLog.Count > 0)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Encoding utf8NoBom = new UTF8Encoding(false);
                        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(_logFilePath, append:true, encoding:utf8NoBom, bufferSize:65536))
                        {
                            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                            while (_fifoLog.TryTake(out string line))
                            {
                                sb.AppendLine(line);
                                if (_echoToConsole == true) { Console.WriteLine(line); }
                            }
                            sw.Write(sb.ToString());
                        }
                    }
                    catch (IOException)         // IOException is semi-expected
                    {
                        // Do nothing. Unprocessed items will still be waiting in the fifo for the next attempt.
                    }                            
                }
                
                _flushCts.Token.WaitHandle.WaitOne(SLEEP_MILLISECONDS);
            }
        }
```

Comment: The lowest friction solution would be to use a logging library like Serilog which already takes care of buffering and writing log messages with minimal overhead

Comment: Sometimes, depending on whether your environment/culture supports this. There could also be non-log tasks that write to network drives that this question/answer might help someone with in the future.

Comment: `whether your environment/culture supports this` it does, otherwise it will be impossible to work with *ANY* .NET Core version - which includes .NET 5 and later. .NET Core itself uses ILogger everywhere and so do all worthwhile NuGet packages. Saying you can't use logging is close enough to saying you can't use .NET at all. And if the argument is "we can only use what's in the SDK" then you can't even use .NET Framework, because many core libraries are only available through NuGet

Comment: By "environment/culture" I'm referring to employer policies, not a .NET environment.

Comment: That's what I refer to as well. No company policy can mandate where the sun rises from or Microsoft's .NET works. If you want to use either .NET Framework or .NET Core you *have* to use NuGet packages. If you want security, it's infinitely better to use a tested library than building your own and having to find all the problems yourself. This code leaks strings and Encoding objects, and pays a big overhead by opening the stream over and over. You'd avoid the IO problem completely if you opened the file only once.

Comment: You could improve logging a lot if you replaced BlockingQueue and all relevant code with a Channel and a single writer method that opens the file, maybe in Shared mode if you want others to read from it and *then* start reading asynchronously from the channel and writing to the file. The code doesn't do any kind of formatting either, so the StringBuilder isn't useful. The StreamWriter already uses a buffer, so you gain nothing by concatenating multiple lines before writing them

Comment: You should also consider using the ILogger middleware even in .NET Framework instead of rolling your own. Everything uses it so sooner or later you'll have to adapt your custom logging code to work with libraries that expect ILogger to be available

Comment: `leaks strings and Encoding objects` How so? In hindsight I can see the encoding object can be hoisted outside the loop, and these objects are left to garbage collection, but I don't see a leak per se.

Comment: `left to garbage collection` when they can be avoided *is* a leak. Logging is a high traffic process so generating extra strings results in several thousand extra objects that take memory and have to be garbage collected. GC freezes the application while it works, so thousands of extra strings can have a very big impact.

Comment: If you know of a magic way to make .NET strings not be immutable heap objects, I would like to learn about this.

Comment: That's the kind of problem already solved in logging libraries, using ReadOnlySpan, Memory<>, [logging source generation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/logger-message-generator). Why are you reinventing the wheel? In this case though what I'm saying is you don't need Stringbuilder at all, you can just use `sw.WriteLine(line);` directly. The StringBuilder is only acting as an expensive buffer here. Your `StreamWriter` already has a 65KB buffer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257039/discussion-between-amonroejj-and-panagiotis-kanavos).